# While loop gets executes 4 times while it shouldn't

Tags: c#

**EDIT!**

*My mistake has been found. I forgot to close the for loop.*

*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*

I have a StreamReader to read from a file and add every line into a listbox.
But for whatever reason the while loop executes 4 times, but I just give it one impulse.
In the end I have the same listbox items 4 times.

Here's my code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    listboxDates.Items.Clear();
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");


    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        listboxDates.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
    for (int n = listboxDates.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
    {
        string removelistitem = "users";
        if (listboxDates.Items[n].ToString().Contains(removelistitem))
        {
            listboxDates.Items.RemoveAt(n);
        }
    }

string file = Convert.ToString(listboxDates.Items[3].ToString());
using (StreamReader stRead = new StreamReader(file))
{
   while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
   {
      listboxNames.Items.Add(stRead.ReadLine());
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you convert a `String` to `String`?

Comment: The string conversion was given to us by our teacher. He said that "we shall not touch it"

Comment: However, either use `ToString` or `ConvertToString`, both together is pointless. Apart from that, what means "I just give it one impulse"? You have only one line in the file?

Comment: the file consists of ca. 38 lines. I mean that there is one button press that acts like 4.

Comment: if this is your teacher trying to teach you good coding practise you should question `Convert.ToString(listboxDates.Items[3].ToString())` This is poor coding and would be picked up by even a junior dev as plain wrong.

Comment: @NilsFahle: If the problem is that clicking a button seems to act like four button clicks then you'll need to give us the code around the button. That having been said put a break point at the start of your click event handler and at the beginning of this method (if they are not the same) and then debug to find out what is happening. While debugging you should be able to see it hit the loop four times (if that is what is happening) and have seen where each of them originated.

Comment: We already figured that it is wrong. He just said "not to touch it.". I recognized the double conversion, but it's not an answer to the question.

Comment: You could clear the contents of your listbox just before you loop through the file: `listboxNames.Items.Clear(); while (...) ...`. Would it be a good solution for you in this case?

Comment: @chris there is the next problem. It's just the while loop thats executed 4 times. The code inbetween works just fine, but I'll add it.

Comment: If the while loop is being called four times then the using around it must be called four times and likewise the string conversion before it. Unless you mean the code inside the loop is being run four times (though I'd expected if you have 38 lines it to add 38 items to your list).

Comment: Is the while-loop executed four times or does it simply iterate 4 times which means that you have 4 lines in the file?

Comment: @TimSchmelter the while loop adds all 38 lines 4 times.

Comment: Isn't it cleaner to have one foreach loop in which you choose what you add and what you don't add? Rather than adding everything and then filtering

Comment: have you checked if there is a event for example, which is called when adding items to the list, which then implicitly calls your add logic again? how about debugging and watching the callstack?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(FILENAME).Where(line => line.Trim().Length > 0).ToArray());
```

Comment: Your answer gives me this: "Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Visual C#\adhistory2\adhistory2\MainWindow.xaml.cs 52 44 adhistory2"

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az(v=vs.90).aspx  see example section

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain what it does and add some references to it